# Sum of the series $(i)$ and $(ii)$

Tags: summation, summation-method

Find the sum of the series: 
$(i)1+\frac{2}{9}+\frac{2.5}{9.18}+\frac{2.5.8}{9.18.27}+\cdots +\infty$
$(ii)1+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{7}{16}+\frac{13}{64}+\cdots +\infty$
The answer providing my book is :$(i)\frac{9}{4}^{\frac{1}{3}},(ii)\frac{8}{3}$.
i couldn't think of how to start.Because i didn't find any helpful pattern to go further.Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.[image: the question]

Comment: Am I right : 1) $\sum \frac{2 \cdot ... \cdot (3k+2)}{9 \cdot ... \cdot 9k}$ ?

Comment: It's better you to describe the behavior of $a_{n}$. Because it's impossible to determine the series.

Comment: the answer providing my book is $\frac{9}{4}^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Can you written the sum without summation notation @openspace

Comment: @openspace my book didn't provide any information about $a_n$ :)

Comment: May I have a look at your book ? It would be nice if you give us good information about task.

Comment: sorry @openspace.but math.stackexchange didn't allow me to add picture for the seek of 10 repuations :)

Comment: Now you have 11.

Comment: i didn't think you get extra info from my picture :) there is nothing say about $a_n$ @Openspace

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know what it's supposed to be .

1) I supposed that numerator always increased by next even number : $3 = 1 + \color{blue}{2}$, then $7 = 3 +\color{blue}{4}$ and so on.
And denominator is $4^{k}$.
So we have $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k(k+1)+1}{4^{k}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k(k+1)}{4^{k}} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{k}}$. The second term is geometric progression and the first one is computed by : $\displaystyle S(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k+1}}{4^{k}} = x^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{4^{k}} = \frac{4x^{1}}{4-x}$ , so you have $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k(k+1)}{4^{k}} = S''(x)|_{x = 1} = (\frac{4x}{4-x})''|_{x=1} = \frac{32}{27}$

Comment: According to your solution i get $1.S_{\infty} =\frac{68}{27}$ :) Is the solution provided by the book is wrong ? @openspace

Comment: @raihanhossain I see only the answer in book. Its impossible to guess sequence by answer

Comment: Ok @openspace .Thanks a lot for your hard working sir :)

Comment: @raihanhossain no problem , I'll think about second series , sequence looks easier ,  but it's hard to evaluate (for me)

Comment: Ok @openspace I will wait your answer :)